# リストに独自クラスの要素を追加したい

Tags: unity3d, c#

UnityでC#を用いています。
独自クラスをリストで扱いたいのですが、要素を一行で追加しようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TEST : MonoBehaviour {
    public class test {
        public int    I;
        public float  F;
        public string S;
    }

    private List<test> qwe = new List<test>();
    private List<string> asd = new List<string>();

    void Start() {
        asd.Add("あああ");

        test q = new test();
        q.I = 1;
        q.F = 2.5f;
        q.S = "いいい";
        qwe.Add(q); // バラバラなら追加できた

        qwe.Add (new test(2, 3.5f, "ううう")); // この方法でできるはず？

        Debug.Log(asd[0]+"  "+qwe[0].S+"  "+qwe[1].S);
        Debug.Break();
    }
}
```

発生したエラーは次の３つです。

```
Assets/Scripts/TEST.cs(24,51): error CS1729: The type `TEST.test' does not contain a constructor that takes `3' arguments

Assets/Scripts/TEST.cs(24,21): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<TEST.test>.Add(TEST.test)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/TEST.cs(24,21): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `TEST.test'
```

サイト内のコードをコピーしたりもしたのですが、何故か動作しません。
正常に追加するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Comment: `<test>` が正しく表示されるよう編集しました: インデント4つでコードブロックとして表示されます (コードを選択して編集フォームの上の `{}` ボタンで一発でできます)。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

最初のエラーについては、

```
 public class test {
    public int    I;
    public float  F;
    public string S;
    public test(int i, float f, string s) {
        I = i;
        F = f;
        S = s;
    }
}
```

と、3つの引数を取るコンストラクタを実装してはいかがでしょうか。(ついでに、メンバ変数は自動プロパティで定義するのが良い気もしました。)

`List`の扱いについてはPITAさんの書かれているように、<>で格納する型を指定されると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 5):

ジェネリックスを使います。
Tは、任意の型を指定します。

例:

```
List<test> items = new List<test>();
```

testクラスには、引数を受け取るコンストラクタが見つかりません。
コンストラクタを実装するか、オブジェクト初期化を使用します。

```
var o = new test(){
     I = 10,
     F = 2.5f,
     S = "hoge"
};
```

なお、これは、o.I = 10; 等とした場合と同じです。